# Population growth - when will two populations be equal?

Tags: arithmetic

I have three populations

```
a <- 100 
b <- 100000
c <- 75000
```

Population `a` growths 10% per year while population `b` growths 1% per year and population `c` growths 2% per year.

How many years are necessary for the total population of `a` be the same of `b` and of `c`?

I have tried to solve this problem by using the compound interest formula (but I am not sure whether this is the right way to do it).

If so, how can I find `t` in this comparison so that it returns `TRUE`?

```
a * ((1 + 0.1) ^ (1 * t)) == b * ((1 + 0.01) ^ (1 * t))
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The population of A after $t $ years is $100 (1+.1)^t$.

B is $100,000 (1+.01)^t $

C is $75,000 (1+.02)^t$

You can find when any two of them are equal by setting 2 equal to each other and solving for $t $.  But there's no reason to believe there will be a time all three are equal.  There might be.  But there's no reason to assume there is.

So $A =B $ when $100*1.1^t= 100000*1.01^t $ or when $A/B=1$ so $\frac {100*1.1^t}{100000*1.01^t}=1$

So $\frac {100}{100000}(\frac {1.1}{1.01}^t)=1$

$10^{-3}(\frac {1.1}{1.01})^t=1$

$ (\frac {1.1}{1.01})^t=10^3$

$t=\log_{\frac {1.1}{1.01}}10^3$

$=\frac {\log_{10}10^3}{\log_{10}\frac {1.1}{1.01}} =\frac 3 {\log_{10}\frac {1.1}{1.01}}$

Comment: Thanks, @fleablood. You are right. I should not assume that they will be equal in t years. Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for solving it @fleablood. I was not sure how to solve it for 't' anyways. Now you reminded me of my Math classes. Cheers,